# Python - change variable outside for loop based on item name in loop

Tags: python

I'm sure this is simple, I don't think I have the language to come up with the right query. I want to use the list item I give in a for loop to update a variable outside the for loop.

```
import random

itemlist = ['cat', 'dog']

catcount = 0
dogcount = 0

for item in itemlist:
    ((item))count = random.randint(1,101)
```

Using `itemcount` doesn't work, it just gives a random integer to `itemcount`, instead of giving a random integer to `catcount` or `dogcount`. I want `catcount` or `dogcount` to update with the random integer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dynamic variables is almost never a good idea. Use a dictionary instead:

```
import random

itemlist = ['cat', 'dog']

count = { 'cat': 0, 'dog': 0 }

for item in itemlist:
    count[item] = random.randint(1,101)
```

Then to access `dogcount` just do `count['dog']`, and the same for `catcount`.

I'm assuming the purpose is to have a new variable for each item in `itemlist`. You can use a `defaultdict` in that case if the keys (`cat, dog`) are not predetermined. `defaultdict` inherits `dict`, so it will work like a normal `dict`:

```
from collections import defaultdict
import random

itemlist = ['cat', 'dog', 'foo', 'bar', 'baz']

count = defaultdict(int)

for item in itemlist:
    count[item] = random.randint(1,101)

print(count) # defaultdict(int, {'cat': 100, 'dog': 84, 'foo': 34, 'bar': 11, 'baz': 42})
```

Even better, you can use a one-line dictionary comprehension:

```
count = {item: random.randint(1,101) for item in itemlist}
```